# Changing heading text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

**HTML:**

```
    <button id='ro' class='ro'></button>
    <button id='eng' class='eng'></button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
  $('#ro').click(function(){
            $('h1').text('Bine a&#355i venit!');
            $('p1').text('Pathifier &#238&#351i propune s&#259 ajute tinerii din &#238ntreaga &#355ar&#259 s&#259 i&#351i g&#259seasc&#259 o facultate cu profilul dorit l&#259s&#226ndu-le libertatea s&#259-&#351i aleag&#259 ora&#351ul potrivit.');
            alert('ma-ta');
    });

    $('#eng').click(function(){
            $('h1').text('Welcome');
            $('p1').text('Pathifier s goal is to help teens all around Romania to choose the university that fits them best, also allowing them to find the perfect city which has that university ');
    });
```

The two buttons are meant to change the language of the page but I they are not working. Why? What did I do wrong?

Comment: why are you passing e as a parameter?

Comment: This works for me. Are you including jquery?

Comment: There was nothing wrong with passing the *event* object `e` within the function as OP did.

Comment: But still, why doesn't it work?

Comment: So one can access the event's methods, depending on the need. You've probably seen the more common property: `e.preventDefault();` which will prevent the *default* action per the `.click()` event. Useful in *halting* a form submission, and/or adding click events to anchor `<a>` elements without following the `href="example.com"`

Comment: I think you may not be including your script at all or you are missing jQuery reference of something else like that.

Comment: See working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/13/

Comment: @marcus thanks for the explanation. I have never had to prevent default actions from taking place, i usually find a different way to handle form submissions. Good tip though! Does it cost unnecessary overhead to pass it and not use it?

Comment: Those were just a couple of examples per its more *common* usages. There are countless ways that the *event* object comes in handy. Just depends on your needs.

Comment: Events are not just for form submissions. Say you had a link `<a href="example.com" class="my-link">Link</a>` that you *also* wanted a click event on, but you want the click event to fire and *not* take the user to the URL in question. You'd simply use the `event.preventDefault();` within (pseudo) `$('.my-link).click( function(event) { event.preventDefault(); // do other stuff });` So your link (example.com) is still accessible with JS *off* which is a good thing. But it doesn't fire immediately with JS *on*. Accessibility is often quite overlooked by many developers.

Answer (score -1):

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var cow =  'Check out this image <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" style="border:2px solid #ccc;" /></a> and one with a width <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="700" align="left" /></a>';
    $('#ro').click(function(){
        $('h1').text('Bine a&#355i venit!');
        $('p').text('Pathifier &#238&#351i propune s&#259 ajute tinerii din &#238ntreaga &#355ar&#259 s&#259 i&#351i g&#259seasc&#259 o facultate cu profilul dorit l&#259s&#226ndu-le libertatea s&#259-&#351i aleag&#259 ora&#351ul potrivit.');
        alert('ma-ta');
    });

    $('#eng').click(function(){
        $('h1').text('Welcome');
        $('p').text('Pathifier s goal is to help teens all around Romania to choose the university that fits them best, also allowing them to find the perfect city which has that university ');
    });
});
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>One Page Wonder - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/one-page-wonder.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>

<body>

<button id='ro' class='ro'></button>
<button id='eng' class='eng'></button>

<h1>KLJLKJ</h1>
<p>lkasjdflsj</p>
<h1>KLJLKJ</h1>
<p>lkasjdflsj</p>
<h1>KLJLKJ</h1>
<p>lkasjdflsj</p>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<!-- my js -->
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This works. Make sure you are including jQuery and your js file after jQuery.

Comment: For sake of brevity, don't include all the *extras*, ie. bootstrap CSS/JS, relative links to files on *your* server, Gooele fonts, HTML5 shivs, respond.js, etc. lol. Just inline the javascript and keep it simple so your example(s) can be easily extrapolated and executed (without alteration) on another server.